# Spring Boot : Detaching Queued Operation

Tags: spring, spring-boot, queue

In spring boot when I tried save any data it gives

> : HHH000496: Detaching an uninitialized collection with queued
> operations from a session

I have already tried adding @Transitional keyword but it did not work.Is there any suggestion for this issue?